# Weird error 'The method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available'

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, geth-debugging

I am trying to use truffle to migrate with the following command

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

and I face the following error

**The method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available**

I tried to enter `geth` and inspect using

```
> eth.accounts

Error: The method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at get (web3.js:6247:38)
    at <unknown>
```

Anyone has similar experience or know how to solve it ?

Comment: did you enable eth in the cmd or not? something like `--rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the parameters using `--rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"`

[Source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/427#issuecomment-247312924)

Comment: Is it intentional that `web3` appears twice there?

Comment: No it is not! I will edit it and remove the duplicate.