# Why am I getting "Error: unknown account" when trying to send ETH using eth.sendTransaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I have an ETH testnet set up using this [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i4/docker-compose.yml) file.

When I try to send 1 wei from the "buffer" account `0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28` to the test account `0x6d179e1d7715b6b2eedf82b16b90db3fd4cd64a3` using the following commands, I get the error ùnknown account`:

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Buffer account**

The buffer account is the account in which all mined ETH ends up. It is specified in the [genesis.json](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i4/genesis.json) file:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The buffer account exists on the testnet and when I run

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8178 \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_getBalance", "params":["0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28","latest"], "id":1}'
```

I get the expected result: The buffer account has `0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` ETH:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
```

**Test account**

I created the test account myself using

```
geth account new --password address1pw.txt
```

It appears in the output of

```
geth account list
```

[image: Screenshot 3]

**Question**

What do I need to do in order to transfer 1 wei from the buffer account to the test account?

**Update 1**

Changing the request to

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: '0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339', to: '0x6D179e1d7715b6b2eeDF82b16B90db3fd4cd64A3', value: 1});
```

results in

```
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:20(10)
```

`0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339` is `ETH_ADDRESS` specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

**Update 2**

Changing the request to

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: '0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339', to: '0x6D179e1d7715b6b2eeDF82b16B90db3fd4cd64A3', gas:8000000 , value: 1});
```

results in

```
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:20(12)
```

**Update 3**

In the [genesis.json](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i4/genesis.json) file the account from which I try to send ETH appears in the `alloc` section:

```
    "alloc": {
        "411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28": {
            "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
```

**Update 4:**

Here is how the ETH is being initialized: The file [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/ulamlabs/geth-poa-testnet/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) is run where I find this:

```
echo $ETH_PASSWORD > /tmp/eth_pass
echo $ETH_PRIVATE_KEY > /tmp/eth_private_key

geth --datadir /data init ./.genesis.json
geth --datadir /data account import --password /tmp/eth_pass /tmp/eth_private_key || true
```

`ETH_PASSWORD` and `ETH_PRIVATE_KEY` come from the vriables in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/i4/docker-compose.yml) file:

```
  geth:
    image: ulamlabs/geth-poa-testnet:latest
    environment:
      - ETH_PASSWORD=QfdxTYxkwASj
      - ETH_PRIVATE_KEY=0d0b4c455973c883bb0fa584f0078178aa90c571a8f1d40f28d2339f4e757dde
      - ETH_ADDRESS=0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339
    ports:
      - 8178:8178
      - 8546:8546
    volumes:
      - ./genesis.json:/app/genesis.json
```

It seems that the buffer account (`411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28`) is not created when the container is created.

**Update 5:**

I ran following commands in the geth shell:

```
echo carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes > buffer-pw.txt
echo 766df34218d5a715018d54789d6383798a1885088d525670802ed8cf152db5b4 > buffer-private-key.txt
geth account import --datadir /data  --password buffer-pw.txt buffer-private-key.txt

echo a-turkey-is-a-chicken-designed-by-a-committee > exchange-pw.txt
echo b07aedf303f832664eb7a5295be737776cb1ad17a277ec287b3b3c7bac154e5e > exchange-private-key.txt
geth account import --datadir /data  --password exchange-pw.txt exchange-private-key.txt
```

When I check the balance of the buffer account using

```
geth attach http://localhost:8178
eth.getBalance("0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28");
```

I get this output:

```
9.04625697166532776746648320380374280103671755200316906558262375061821325312e+74
```

Then I tried to send 1 wei from the buffer account to the exchange account again:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: '0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28', to: '0x190FD61ED8fE0067f0f09EA992C1BF96209bab66', value: 1});
```

I get the error

```
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at <eval>:1:20(10)
```

I tried to unlock the account using the following commands, without success:

- `eth.unlockAccount('0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28', 'carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes', 600).then(console.log('Account unlocked!'));`
- `web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28', 'carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes', 600).then(console.log('Account unlocked!'));`

[image: Error messages when trying to unlock the account]

**Update 6:**

Modified the [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) of the Docker image with `geth` so that test accounts are included and the personal API is enabled.

Then, modified [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file to use that changed geth image.

Now unlocking the buffer account and sending money from it seems to work.

Comment: To send ether from an account in geth console you need the account to listed by geth and its private key unlocked. So the only account you can use is `0x6D179e1d7715b6b2eeDF82b16B90db3fd4cd64A3`. One solutions is to import the key in geth for example using https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth-or-mist, or to use another wallet like metamask and connect to geth http endpoint.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks. See update 3. In `genesis.json` the account `411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28` is given a lot of test ETH. I want to be able to send ETH from this account. I (wrongly) assumed that if this account appears in `genesis.json` file it will be automatically created. It isn't. What do I need to do in order to send test ETH from `411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28`?

Comment: @Ismael Should I just create an account for `411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28` using `geth account new`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the account has enough ETH, geth requires the private key to sign the transaction. To import the private key in geth you can proceed like in the link, `geth account new` will create a new account.

Comment: @Ismael Done, see update 5. Now I need to find out how to unlock an account or enter the password when sending a transaction.

Comment: For security reasons personal api is disabled by default see this answer how to enable it https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/58167, also you might have to allow unsafe unlocks `--allow-insecure-unlock`, see more options here https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks. Now it works (see update 6).

Comment: Great! It would be nice if you can add the final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by accounts missing in the geth testnet. If an account appears in `genesis.json` it does not mean that the respective account will automatically be created.

Therefore the first step to fixing the problem is to modify the [existing entrypoin.sh](https://github.com/ulamlabs/geth-poa-testnet/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) so that the accounts are actually created:

```
#
# Create buffer account (start)
# 
echo carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes > /tmp/buffer_pass
echo 766df34218d5a715018d54789d6383798a1885088d525670802ed8cf152db5b4 > /tmp/buffer_private_key
geth account import --datadir /data --password /tmp/buffer_pass /tmp/buffer_private_key
#
# Create buffer account (end)
#

#
# Create exchange account (start)
# 
echo a-turkey-is-a-chicken-designed-by-a-committee > /tmp/exchange_pass
echo b07aedf303f832664eb7a5295be737776cb1ad17a277ec287b3b3c7bac154e5e > /tmp/exchange_private_key
geth account import --datadir /data  --password /tmp/exchange_pass  /tmp/exchange_private_key
#
# Create exchange account (end)
#
```

Also, in order for the `eth.unlockAccount` call to work, we need to enable the personal API when starting `geth` by adding `--rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"` to the original call.

**Before**

```
exec geth --config .config.toml --allow-insecure-unlock --nousb --verbosity $ETH_VERBOSITY --gcmode=archive --mine --miner.threads 1 --unlock $ETH_ADDRESS --password /tmp/eth_pass
```

**After**

```
exec geth --config .config.toml --allow-insecure-unlock --nousb --verbosity $ETH_VERBOSITY --gcmode=archive --mine --miner.threads 1 --unlock $ETH_ADDRESS --password /tmp/eth_pass --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"
```

The [resulting entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet/blob/master/entrypoint.sh) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

export ETH_VERBOSITY=${ETH_VERBOSITY:-1}
export ETH_CHAIN_ID=${ETH_CHAIN_ID:-5555}

replace_env() {
  for key in $(env | sed 's;=.*;;' | grep ETH_); do
    val=$(eval echo \$$key)  # sh doesn't support indirect substitution
    sed -i "s|\$$key|$val|g" $1
  done
}

# replace $ETH_... strings with env variable values without overwriting genesis.json
cp genesis.json .genesis.json
cp config.toml .config.toml
replace_env .genesis.json
replace_env .config.toml

echo $ETH_PASSWORD > /tmp/eth_pass
echo $ETH_PRIVATE_KEY > /tmp/eth_private_key

geth --datadir /data init ./.genesis.json
geth --datadir /data account import --password /tmp/eth_pass /tmp/eth_private_key || true

#
# Create buffer account (start)
# 
echo carsdrivefasterbecausetheyhavebrakes > /tmp/buffer_pass
echo 766df34218d5a715018d54789d6383798a1885088d525670802ed8cf152db5b4 > /tmp/buffer_private_key
geth account import --datadir /data --password /tmp/buffer_pass /tmp/buffer_private_key
#
# Create buffer account (end)
#

#
# Create exchange account (start)
# 
echo a-turkey-is-a-chicken-designed-by-a-committee > /tmp/exchange_pass
echo b07aedf303f832664eb7a5295be737776cb1ad17a277ec287b3b3c7bac154e5e > /tmp/exchange_private_key
geth account import --datadir /data  --password /tmp/exchange_pass  /tmp/exchange_private_key
#
# Create exchange account (end)
# 

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
  exec geth --config .config.toml --allow-insecure-unlock --nousb --verbosity $ETH_VERBOSITY --gcmode=archive --mine --miner.threads 1 --unlock $ETH_ADDRESS --password /tmp/eth_pass --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal"
else
  exec "$@"
fi
```

Finally, we need to replace the old docker image in `docker-compose.yml` with the new one, i. e. change the line from

```
    image: ulamlabs/geth-poa-testnet:latest
```

to

```
    image: mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet:v1
```

[Final version](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) of `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
#
# BTC testnet setup (start)
#
  node:
    image: ulamlabs/bitcoind-custom-regtest:latest
  electrumx:
    image: lukechilds/electrumx:latest
    links:
      - node
    ports:
      - "51001:50001"
      - "51002:50002"
    environment:
      - NET=regtest
      - COIN=BitcoinSegwit
      - DAEMON_URL=http://test:test@node:19001
  explorer:
    image: ulamlabs/btc-rpc-explorer:latest
    links:
      - node
      - electrumx
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    environment:
      - BTCEXP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - BTCEXP_BITCOIND_URI=http://test:test@node:19001
      - BTCEXP_ELECTRUMX_SERVERS=tls://electrumx:50002
      - BTCEXP_ADDRESS_API=electrumx
#
# BTC testnet setup (end)
#


#
# ETH testnet setup (start)
#
  geth:
    image: mentiflectax/geth-poa-testnet:v1
    environment:
      - ETH_PASSWORD=QfdxTYxkwASj
      - ETH_PRIVATE_KEY=0d0b4c455973c883bb0fa584f0078178aa90c571a8f1d40f28d2339f4e757dde
      - ETH_ADDRESS=0c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e654993339
    ports:
      - 8178:8178
      - 8546:8546
    volumes:
      - ./genesis.json:/app/genesis.json

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=500'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  blockscout:
    image: ulamlabs/blockscout:latest
    links:
      - geth
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:@postgres:5432/postgres?ssl=false
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_VARIANT=geth
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_HTTP_URL=http://geth:8178
      - ETHEREUM_JSONRPC_WS_URL=ws://geth:8546
      - MIX_ENV=prod
      - BLOCKSCOUT_HOST=localhost
      - COIN=eth
      - NETWORK=POA
      - SUBNETWORK=Local Testnet

#
# ETH testnet setup (end)
#
```

It refers to [genesis.json](https://github.com/mentiflectax/minimal-crypto-exchange/blob/master/genesis.json) with the following content:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 5555,
        "clique": {
            "period": 60,
            "epoch": 30000
        },
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip150Block": 0,
        "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0,
        "byzantiumBlock": 0,
        "constantinopleBlock": 0,
        "petersburgBlock": 0,
        "istanbulBlock": 0,
        "muirGlacierBlock": 0
    },
    "extraData": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c56352F05De44C9b5BA8bcF9BDEc7e6549933390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
        "411167FeFecAD12Da17F9063143706C39528aa28": {
            "balance": "0x200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "nonce": "0x0",
    "timestamp": "0x5eaa7b09",
    "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
    "difficulty": "0x1",
    "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "number": "0x0",
    "gasUsed": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Then, it is possible to start BTC and ETH testnets by running `docker-compose up -d` in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file above.